# Oracle Date returns updated date instaed of actual date while retrieving through HIbernate's JPA implementation

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jpa, timestamp

I have a table USER with 2 column in it (createdOn,UpdatedOn) of DataType 'Date' in Oracle.

While saving data i am using (Java.util Date)

`@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
@Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;`

I am trying to persist data by saveAndFlush() method via JpaRepository.

`System.out.println("TIME STRING : "+user.getCreatedOn().toString());
System.out.println("TIME STRING : "+user.getUpdatedOn().toString());`

`TIME STRING : Wed Jan 20 10:57:13 GMT 2016
TIME STRING : Wed Jan 20 10:57:13 GMT 2016`

Although there is no issue on persisting but while retrieving it is always printing the current Date and Time regardless of what is present in DB.

Can anybody please help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you check the database what is being persisted there?

Comment: The database has application date and time    createdDate: 12-JAN-16 12:27:24 and UpdatedDate: 20-JAN-16 10:57:13.No problem here ..its only upon retrieval.

Comment: while debugging the object fieled contain the DB value but on sout print, it is printing the current date Time value.

Comment: Try using SimpleDateFormatter to get the string ouput instead of toString.

Comment: It is printing the same value again even though by using SimpleDateFormat..No clue what so ever .. why the correct value is coming while on debug mode but not on print.

Comment: The only way this is possible is that `getCreatedOn()` and `getUpdatedOn()` return `new Date()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response..it was indeed the setter method issue. I was ignoring coz we normally generate it by IDE.but it was there modified by someone else.thanks again